# alias for chain methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, self-join

I have a self-join association for users.
This is my current data

[Click to view data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSIbx.png)

My user model
**User.rb**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User", optional: true
  belongs_to :father, class_name: "User", optional: true
end
```

I am able to execute the following in rails console.

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.find(1)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "rj", mother_id: 3, father_id: 2>

irb(main):002:0> user.father
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 2, name: "father", mother_id: 4, father_id: 5>

irb(main):003:0> user.father.father
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 5, name: "grandfather", mother_id: nil, father_id: nil>
```

In short, I am able to get the object of rj's father's father (grandfather) and rj's father's mother (grandmother) if I do `user.father.father` or `user.father.mother`

Is there a way for me to create an alias such as `user.grandfather` and `user.grandmother` to get the same result instead?

Comment: Your has_one declarations here are ignored and can be removed, JFYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User", optional: true
  belongs_to :father, class_name: "User", optional: true
  has_one :grandfather, through: :father, source: :father
  has_one :grandmother, through: :father, source: :mother
end
```

Comment: People have two sets of grandparents.

Comment: OP define explicitly grandfather: `user.father.father` and grandmother `user.father.mother`, so basically it's ok although maybe in english it's not. @DaveNewton

Comment: @DaveNewton  yep, but to simplify it, I am just using father's side as an example rather than both parent's!

Comment: @LamPhan Thank you for your answer, this is what I am searching for!

Answer (score 0):

In User.rb model, add the below methods

```
def paternal_grandfather
   father&.father
end

def paternal_grandmother
  father&.mother
end

def maternal_grandfather
   mother&.father
end

def maternal_grandmother
  mother&.mother
end
```

Or, In combined form, we can use the methods as

```
def grandfather
  father&.father || mother&.father
end

def grandmother
  father&.mother || mother&.mother
end
```

Use it as `user.grandfather` and `user.grandmother`

Comment: But isn't mother's father a grandfather too?

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it will work for you.

Comment: @spickermann yep, but to simplify it, I am just using father's side as an example rather than both parent's!

Comment: @ShamsulHaque Thank you for this approach, it works but will create two SQL queries as the console shows, which will hit the database twice. Not sure if this is recommended in real-world situations.